# Need help in understanding how this particular Constraint Layout works

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-constraintlayout

I was going through a Udacity course on Android development and found this example of Constraintlayout (though I have shown **only a part** of the xml code and screen shot here). I have a hard time understanding how this is working.

xml layout file snippet:

```
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tableHeaderImage"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewDepartureTime"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.33" />

    <!-- COMPLETED (12) Create an ImageView for the blue table's body -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tableImage"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tableHeaderImage"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewTerminal"/>


    <!-- COMPLETED (13) Create a TextView for each of the labels and text fields in the blue table -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTerminalLabel"
        android:text="@string/terminal_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tableHeaderImage"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewTerminal"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textViewTerminal"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tableHeaderImage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewGateLabel"
        android:text="@string/gate_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tableHeaderImage"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewGate"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textViewGate"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tableHeaderImage"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSeatLabel"
        android:text="@string/seat_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tableHeaderImage"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textViewSeat"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewSeat"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tableHeaderImage"
        />

    <TextView
        tools:text="@string/terminal"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewTerminal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tableImage"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tableImage"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/tableImage"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:textAlignment="center" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewGate"
        tools:text="@string/gate"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tableImage"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/tableImage"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tableHeaderImage"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tableImage"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSeat"
        tools:text="@string/seat"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tableImage"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tableImage"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/tableImage"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_width="120dp" />
```

And the corresponding layout is:

[image]

As we see the first `ImageView` (tableHeaderImage) is used for the header of the table and the second `ImageView` (tableImage) is used for the content of the table.

(The layout `@+id/textViewDepartureTime` is simply above 'tableHeaderImage' and I have not shown here for simplicity)

I can understand how Table header is formed (`@+id/tableHeaderImage`) clearly.

But I dont understand how content table (`@+id/tableImage`) is formed.

As we can see in the code the content table has `0dp` width and height and three `TextView`s (namely `@+id/textViewTerminal` , `@+id/textViewGate` ,`@+id/textViewSeat`) 'somehow' 'expand' this content table beyond `0dp`.

And I am not getting how this expansion of content table has taken place(Especially the vertical expansion of it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see, `@+id/textViewTerminal` has a height of wrap_content, which means that its height depends on the text size attribute value, which is currently `@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2`, in other words the text size is Regular, 45sp :

[Material Design Typography Styles](https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_10/assets/0Bzhp5Z4wHba3alhXZ2pPWGk3Zjg/style_typography_styles_scale.png)

The height of the `@+id/tableImage` is truly 0dp, but it is defined in a different way by using **constraints** Look at these lines of code from the *tableImage* XML definition:

```
...
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tableHeaderImage"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewTerminal"
...
```

You can see very obviously that the height of the `@+id/tableImage` is defined by the distance from the bottom of the `@+id/tableHeaderImage`
to the bottom of the `@+id/textViewTerminal`  which is defined implicitly by the text size. Let me know if you understand it.

Asking questions is always the fastest way to learn anything.
Good luck with the course.

Comment: I had overlooked the constraints defined in @+id/tableImage and focusing on constraints for terminal/gate/seat textviews to know how these might affect @+id/tableImage.Thanks a lot.